# golang replacing substring of regexp

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to find all occurrences of the following regex `\%\%comp\.[^%]+\%\%` and replace them with `\%comp\.[^%]+\%` (i.e reducing one % from both ends).

What is the easiest way to do this in go, aside from using findallindex matches and cleaning up the string in reverse order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Regexp.ReplaceAll](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAll) method for that. [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/QBqtTKRpWgl):

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\%(\%comp\.([^%]+)\%)\%`)
fmt.Printf("%s\n", re.ReplaceAll([]byte("test%%comp.test%%"), []byte("$1")))

>>> OUTPUT: test%comp.test%
```

Notice, that `$n` is used in replacement string to expand value from nth group in regexp.

Comment: You have an extra `%` at the end of the substitution (OP wants to remove one `%` from both sides). Moreover, you could extend the capturing group (i.e., `%(%comp\.[^%]+%)%`) so you can substitute with just `$1`.